# Disabling the controls using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following table with some rows and want to disable the all the controls inside each row.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<table id="tblChildData">
    <tr id="trChild2">
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td style="height: 30px;">
            <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.childName2) %><%--<br />
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SpouseName,null,new{@Class="field-validation-message"}) %>--%>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 30px; text-align: center;">
            &nbsp;M<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.genderIdChild2,1) %>
            &nbsp;F<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.genderIdChild2,2) %>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 30px; text-align: center;">
            <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ageChild2,new{Style="width:30px;",maxlength=3}) %><%--<br />
                <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.SpouseAge,null,new{@Class="field-validation-message"}) %>--%>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 30px; text-align: center;">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Married<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.maritialStatusChild2,1) %>
            UnMarried<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.maritialStatusChild2,2) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

below is the code for jQuery I have used to disabled the controls inside each table rows:

```
$("#trChild2").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild2").hide();
$("#trChild3").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild3").hide();
$("#trChild4").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild4").hide();
$("#trChild5").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild5").hide();
$("#trChild6").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild6").hide();
$("#trChild7").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild7").hide();
$("#trChild8").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild8").hide();
$("#trChild9").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild9").hide();
$("#trChild10").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild10").hide();
$("#trChild11").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild11").hide();
$("#trChild12").find("input,button,textarea").attr("disabled", true);
$("#trChild12").hide();
```

but I dont know why it is only hiding the table rows but not disabling the controls inside the rows...

I have tried this on jsfiddle also but there it seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3QuT4/1/

Please help me..

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: Just a side note: if you want to disable everybody inside the table why don't you give the table an id and call *$("#mytable").find("input, button").attr("disabled", true);*?

Comment: actually i dont want to disable all the tr inside the table...thats why..i wanted to disable only those tr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign unique ids to each `<tr>` row of the table. You could use the following selector to disable all input fields inside the table:

```
$('table :input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Notice that using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the recommended function to use for disabling fields instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) if you are using jQuery 1.6 or later.

And if you want to disable only certain rows then apply those rows the same class and then:

```
$('table tr.someClassName :input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Using ids and repeating the same jQuery selector for each id seems like a very naïve approach to tackle the problem.